# How can i find the last written image to hard disk in a directory but only types of jpg and raw?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried this :

```
private void DisplayLastTakenPhoto()
        {
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(SavePathTextBox.Text);
            var myFile = directory.GetFiles()
             .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
             .First();
        }
```

I need to find images type of jpg and raw.

Comment: what do you mean by `jpg and raw`?

Comment: Any chance you can use [GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx) method for that? (I'm not sure if you can read documentation, so `GetFile` actually takes search pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is to find files by extension, then this should work.  If you actually need to read file headers, please say that.

```
    public void DisplayLastTakenPhoto()
    {
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp");
        var myFile = directory.EnumerateFiles()
         .Where(f => f.Extension.Equals(".js", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || f.Extension.Equals("raw", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
         .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
         .First();
        Assert.IsNotNull(myFile);
    }
```